# CSS DIV Transition (overlapping)

Tags: html, css, scrollmagic

I've run into an issue which I can't seem to solve, although, I'm fairly certain it's a simple mistake:

I have the following within my index.html body:

```
<div id="header-trigger" class="viewport-fullscreen">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
    <div id="section-trigger-01" class="viewport-fullscreen">
</div>
```

I'm attemping to create a class which I can trigger with ScrollMagic, so the the sliders move to the left side of the screen, this is currently bound to `slider:active` for testing:

```
.viewport-fullscreen{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
.slider{
    background-color: #383838;
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        right:0px;
        clear:both
}
.slider:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #3d3c3c
}

.slider:active{
    right:calc(100% - 0px);
    transition-property: right, left;
    position:absolute;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

The second slider div works fine, it appears grey, and on click slowley slides to the left hand side of the screen. However, if the first slider div is clicked, it'll move in the same way, however, instead of revealing the white background, the other div slider moves up to fill the space. I figured that adding clear:both to the slider would resolve this, but had no luck.

Example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jpvyxv
[image]

Anyone able to give me a heads up?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understood how you want it to work as I skimmed through the post and the code, but I believe it's the `position: absolute;` you add on `:active` that breaks it. Could you perhaps use `position: relative;` instead?

Comment: Ugh! I hate myself so much. Yeah, that was it - I've just changed `:absolute` to `:relative` and it's working fine now. Apologies on not being very clear with the question. Thanks a lot. :)